# Why some functions in IDA can't be searched

Tags: ida, functions

I don't know why but I noticed, on some program I am reversing, that in a section named `.bss`, there functions and I can't find them through the regular search, why is that.

For example, I wanted to search for `_mainScene` but it found me only one functioned named `newMainScene`:
[image]

**EDIT:**
A friend show me that I can search with `Shift+4` in IDA for the names in `.bss`.

Comment: dd? Is normally a pointer and not a function

Comment: What is `dd` ? I know it only from WinDBG as a command. Or you meant `ds`, data segment? Is there a way to search in this?

Comment: dd? = uninitialized dword it is there in your screen shot see the address 0x44ddac and around they are all  a placeholder or a pointer  i dont under stand what you want to search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not looking at functions that you can't reach, but at unassigned variables.

As you said, you are looking at the .bss section. From Wikipedia, the .bss section is

> the portion of an object file, executable, or assembly language code that contains statically-allocated variables that are declared but have not been assigned a value yet.

IDA is showing you this with the `dd` opcode. As @blabb point out, this is an `uninitialized dword`, which mean a dword that was not assigned yet. Exactly what is supposed to be in the .bss section !

Theses variables don't have any hardcoded default values, so they are placed in this section of the binary, waiting to be populated at runtime with dynamic values.

What you can do is to write down the address of the variable that you want to find more about, open up a debugger, let it run a bit (or you can break on a specific function if you know where this variable is being populated), and check the content of this variable by looking at the previously written memory address.

You'll know what type of data is supposed to be inside this variable !

Don't forget to deactivate the ASLR while running the binary (otherwise the address that you saw in IDA would not match naything), or if needed, to rebase your program in IDA.